# Trying to understand output of pyspark dataframe to parquet format conversion

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am running below psypark code (pyspark version is 1.6.0)

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

if __name__ == '__main__':
        conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Testing')
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
        hivec = HiveContext(sc)
        df = hivec.sql("select * from product_replica where product_price>100")
        df.write.option("compression","snappy").mode("overwrite").save("/user/cloudera/practice1/problem8/product/output",format="parquet")
        sc.stop()
```

The output i am getting is as below, even though the parquet files are created in hdfs directory but i cannot read them with parque-tools. I get error .parquet file doesnt exist

[cloudera@quickstart sparkTransformationsPractice]$ spark-submit hive_context.py

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-exec-1.1.0-cdh5.13.0.jar!/shaded/parquet/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.13.0-standalone.jar!/shaded/parquet/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/parquet-format-2.1.0-cdh5.13.0.jar!/shaded/parquet/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.5.0-cdh5.13.0.jar!/shaded/parquet/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/parquet-pig-bundle-1.5.0-cdh5.13.0.jar!/shaded/parquet/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [shaded.parquet.org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory] 19/12/11 11:21:14
>   WARN thread.QueuedThreadPool: 2 threads could not be stopped

Can you please explain what this output means, I think i might be doing something wrong

Comment: Saving dataframe like `df.write.parquet('data_parquet/', mode='overwrite')`, stores it in parquet (with snappy compression). You can check whether data is stored properly or not by creating another dataframe from stored parquet `pdf = spark.read.parquet('data_parquet/'`

Comment: Hello , yes i did what you said.. and i can see the table now by command print(pdf.show(3)) but i cannot see the content of file with parquet-tools head parquet_path. So i guess should be ok.. But thanks !

Comment: '[cloudera@quickstart sparkTransformationsPractice]$ parquet-tools schema /user/cloudera/parquetoutput/part-r-00001-32d4f0a0-253c-4980-9264-a7f04b360c1f.gz.parquet
File /user/cloudera/parquetoutput/part-r-00001-32d4f0a0-253c-4980-9264-a7f04b360c1f.gz.parquet does not exist'

Comment: it's `parquet-tools schema /user/cloudera/parquetoutput/` without the rest.

Comment: Yes but still see same results :(

Comment: `[cloudera@quickstart sparkTransformationsPractice]$ parquet-tools schema /user/cloudera/parquetoutput/
File /user/cloudera/parquetoutput does not exist

[cloudera@quickstart sparkTransformationsPractice]`